# Javascript disable enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable the enter key in a web form. The web form is set up by a Javascript function "initialize". In that function I added the following code:

```
$('html').bind('keypress', function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This works well for every button except one. On most of my screens I have a "continue" button, set up like this (from an open-source third party library):

```
that.continueButton = function (obj) {

        var str = ""

        if (typeof obj==="string") {
            obj = {label: obj}
        }
        if (!obj) {
            obj = {};
        }
        if (!obj.label) {
            obj.label = Experigen.settings.strings.continueButton;
        }

        str += '<input type="button" value="' + obj.label + '" ';
        var spec = [];
        if (obj.hide===true) {
            spec.push("hide:true");
        }
        if (obj.disable===true) {
            spec.push("disable:true");
        }
        spec = spec.length ? ",{" + spec.join(",") + "}" : "";
        //add answer before advancing       
        str += 'onClick="Experigen.screen().continueButtonClick(this' + spec + ');">'
        return str
    }

    /**
     * Forwards the experiment: calls {@link Experigen.trial.advance} or {@link Experigen.advance} as needed
     * @method
     * @memberof Experigen.trial
     */
    that.continueButtonClick = function (caller, spec) {

        //Add training block information and user responses
        if (Experigen.screen().soundbuttons[0] != undefined)
        {   
            Experigen._screens[Experigen.position].Listens = Experigen.screen().soundbuttons[0].presses;
        }

        Experigen._screens[Experigen.position].Answer = $("input[name=answergiven]").val();
        Experigen._screens[Experigen.position].TrainingBlock = Experigen.settings.training_block;

        var comingFrom = Experigen.screen().findCaller(caller);
        if (comingFrom && comingFrom.attr("class")==="trialpartWrapper") {
            Experigen.screen().advance(spec);
        } else {
            Experigen.advance(caller);
        }

    }
```

As you might have guessed, the enter key "clicks" this button and moves the user to the next screen. This is the only button for which the enter key is not disabled. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: Does changing to `keydown` instead of `keypress` make a difference? Also it is weird that you are binding to `html`. It would be better to bind to the `$(document)`.

Comment: My goodness that actually did work (changing keypress to keydown). That must be a record for quickest answer. Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @HH I doubt that's a record, I've see answers to questions in less than a minute of their posting.

Comment: The keydown event occurs when the key is pressed, followed immediately by the keypress event. Then the keyup event is generated when the key is released.

In order to understand the difference between keydown and keypress, it is useful to understand the difference between a "character" and a "key". A "key" is a physical button while a "character" is a symbol typed by pressing a button. In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed.

Comment: @MJB Ok, I understand that. But what is the difference between my continue button and all the other buttons on my form? Why would keypress be good enough for them?

Comment: @epascarello if you wish to add an answer I'd be happy to mark this question closed. I'd add it myself, but I don't think that would be fair to you.

Comment: Give yourself the points ;)

Comment: @epascarello I guess I need them more than you. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @epascarello in the comments above, changing "keypress" to "keydown" does the trick.